# Wordpress template deleted, but still working and showing on template selection

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, themes, frontpage

I have a template front-page.php in my theme. Its name is "Front Page".

My problem is that when I commit changes in this file. It wont reflect on the front end. This happened just yesterday and I don't know what's going on..

I tried deleting this template but, my page that uses this template still uses this (deleted) template. When I edit the page, the selected template is still "Front Page".

Help me guys, Thanks!

Comment: It may be your cache problem. Refresh your page with ctrl+f5 many times and then check it again.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem before and i found the issue was because of duplicate template with same name.You may have duplicate template

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any cache plugin like WP Super Cache then go to WP Dashboard ->plugin's page and delete all cache.